# Can't find GNAT GPS Dependencies Form

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm trying to figure out why the library for GtkAda won't compile with an existing project. I believe I have the PATH and ADA_INCLUDE_PATH pointing to the right folders but the Gtk spec files (e.g., gtk.ads) are not being found during compile.

[Documentation for GPS at Adacore](http://docs.adacore.com/gps-docs/users_guide/_build/html/projects.html#the-project-dependencies-editor) describes *The Project Dependencies Editor* in section 6.9, but this isn't present in the tool menu at Project>Dependencies, where the documentations says it should be found. I can't find it anywhere else in the tool menu of in the Project Properties form.

[image: Project Dependencies form]

Where can I find this form? I'm Using Windows 7 with GNAT 2014 Academic Version and GtkAda 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation I found with GNAT GPL 2015 (PDF only, in `$prefix/share/doc/gps/pdf`) says

> Edit the dependencies between projects through the contextual Project → Dependencies... menu in the Project view.

The “Project view” is the pane on the left hand of the GPS window, click on the “Project” tab. Your project should appear.

You get the contextual (popup) menu by placing the mouse over the item, in this case your project, and pressing the right mouse button.

Looking at the instructions for adding a dependency on another project, I’d have thought it a lot easier to just edit the project file directly.

Comment: That seems to have moved me forward a bit. It placed this line in the project file: limited with "..\..\..\..\..\..\..\GtkAda\lib\gnat\gtkada.gpr";  I don't get the relative referencing:( But I'll look into it some more. ... I changed it to an absolute path, and it still seems to compile.

Comment: I'm not sure why GtkAda did not show up in the list of known projects. It looks like many others are there.

Comment: Here, the “Add From Wizard” route has a “Use relative paths in the projects” checkbox. I’m not sure what makes a project ‘known’, it at least includes projects installed with the compiler and local projects. I expect it’d include those on `ADA_PROJECT_PATH` or `GPR_PROJECT_PATH`.